# Openerp v7 API function field 'one2many' type

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

On the click of a treeview record I want to open a formview. When that formview is opened I have two one2many fields that need to be populated dynamically (in my case I have a list of products and on the click of a product I want to search how many stock moves have been made for this product)

```
def get_last_sales(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    customer_loc_id = self.pool.get('stock.location').search(cr, uid, [('usage', '=', 'customer')])
    result = self.pool.get('stock.move').search(cr, uid, [('product_id', '=', ids), ('location_dest_id', '=', customer_loc_id)])
    print result
    #raise Exception
    return result

def get_last_productions(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None, args=None, kwargs=None):
    production_loc_id = self.pool.get('stock.location').search(cr, uid, [('usage', '=', 'production')])
    result = self.pool.get('stock.move').search(cr, uid, [('product_id', '=', ids), ('location_dest_id', '=', production_loc_id)])
    return result
```

What I want is similar functionality to the `fields.function` field. This should work but it does not:

`'last_sales':fields.function(_get_last_sales, type='one2many', relation='stock.move', readonly=True, store=store_triggers)`

`Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3718, in read
    result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3841, in _read_flat
    res2 = self._columns[f].get(cr, self, ids, f, user, context=context, values=res)
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1152, in get
    result = self._fnct(obj, cr, uid, ids, name, self._arg, context)
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/addons/product/product.py", line 461, in _product_lst_price
    res[product.id] = product.list_price
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 503, in __getattr__
    return self[name]
  File "/home/george/odoo/mattia_v7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 469, in __getitem__
    elif field_column._type in ('one2many', 'many2many') and len(result_line[field_name]):
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()`

I can see on https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/can-i-store-field-function-with-the-type-one2many-356

that this does not seem to be supported. 
Is the answer there correct? Is there any workaround on this?

Comment: Please update your question with *_get_last_sales* method.

Comment: @Odedra Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, storing x2many function or computed fields makes no sense at all. Why? Both types need some special setup, which can't be made on field definition. On one2many you would need the related foreign key on the other model. On many2many you would have to define the table for both models keys.

My experience with odoo showed: use unstored many2many function fields (function needs to return a list of ids in its usual dictionary).

Plus, your functions aren't correct, as @Odedra has mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code:

```
def get_last_sales(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    customer_loc_id = self.pool.get('stock.location').search(cr, uid, [('usage', '=', 'customer')])
    result = {}

    if customer_loc_id:

        for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):

            result[record.id] = self.pool.get('stock.move').search(cr, uid, [('product_id', '=', record.id), ('location_dest_id', '=', customer_loc_id[0])])

    return result

def get_last_productions(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None, args=None, kwargs=None):

    production_loc_id = self.pool.get('stock.location').search(cr, uid, [('usage', '=', 'production')])
    result = {}

    if production_loc_id:

        for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):

            result[record.id] =  self.pool.get('stock.move').search(cr, uid, [('product_id', '=', record.id), ('location_dest_id', '=', production_loc_id[0])])

    return result

'last_sales':fields.function(_get_last_sales, type='one2many', relation='stock.move', readonly=True, string='Last Sales')
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what does this code do? Why should I put this?

Comment: This code will solve your problem. In your code, have many problems. For example you didn't pass value to particular record id. When we use *=* operator, then we need to set proper value. In your case, you have passed list. *(customer_loc_id)* and *(production_loc_id)*

Comment: Thank you for your time and response @Odedra. But my main issue does not lie in these method. My main issue is how to invoke a method when the form view of my record opens up. Please ignore these methods I already have them deleted, I just inserted them to see if they will get invoked.